# How to leak buffer address on the stack?

Tags: buffer-overflow, stack, shellcode

I am new to buffer overflows and I was trying to overwrite the saved RIP to point to a buffer containing a shellcode. The buffer is located onto the stack so its address is randomized. How can I leak it?

Comment: Is your stack executable?